# JavaScript preventDefault not working, neither does return false;

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I've searched this question in Stack Overflow before posting it, but none of the posts found seem to work for me.

I have this:

```
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn) {
    if (elm.addEventListener) {
        elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
        return true;
    }
    else if (elm.attachEvent) {
        var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }
    else {
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }
}
```

and I do this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myLink');

addEvent(el, "click", function(event){
         alert('testing');
        if(event.preventDefault){
            event.preventDefault;
        }
         if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
         }
        return false;
    });
```

where `myLink` is:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="myLink">Click me</a>
```

but when I click the link, it doesn't stop the default event action. I've tested on IE, Firefox and Chrome, with no result.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the code:

```
addEvent(el, "click", function(event){ // event will be undefined in IE
    event = event || window.event; // fallback to window.event in IE

    alert('testing');
    if(event.preventDefault){
        event.preventDefault(); // () was missing here
    }
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works now!! stupid me.. didnt see the missing ()... sorry for that, but thank you so much!!

Comment: Haha thanks, just had this issue myself. Always seem to forget preventDefault is a function call.